# Javascript null checking not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, null-check

I'm using AngularJS as my framework and also connect to a webservice to fetch some JSON data. I have the following code:

```
$login.onlineLogin($scope.credentials).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        if (data !== null ) {
            console.log('Successful Login!');
            console.log('Returned data: ' + data);
        } else {
            console.log('Failed to Login...');
        }

    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('HTTP Error...');
    });
```

Now, when the HTTP call comes back the status could still be 200:OK but the object that it returns could be null, in the case where the user provided the wrong user credentials for example. So what I'm expecting to happen in that case is that if the object is NOT null, it'll print out 'Successful Login!' and then print out the object.

However, what's happening now is that I use some fake credentials, so the webservice returns null. But still the 'Successful Login!' gets printed, and then after it prints 'Returned data: null'... Which doesn't make sense. If the data is null, it should never have even ended up in that code block?

Comment: use  **if (data) {} else {}** instead

Comment: Same thing is happening

Comment: maybe the data returns a string not null but 'null'. try to use typeOf.

Comment: yes console.log(typeof data);

Comment: try if (data != null) or that's just php, just try ))

Comment: ah man do I feel dumb now.. @kdlcruz was right

Comment: @DeanGrobler nice. :). Do you know how to proceed now?

Comment: if() only works falsy or truthy values. So you null, undefined, empty string are considered as falsy value in javascript. You do not need to compare variables.  Simple use `if (data) { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not sure what is the type of your variable use.

```
console.log(typeof variableName)
```

In your case, your problem can be fixed using

```
if (data != 'null') {
...
```

Comment: I actually did this: if (data !== null && typeof data === "object") { ... }

Comment: Good one :). But if you're not sure what is the response I would suggest don't use strict condition !== .

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
if (data !== null ) {
    .....
}
```

use this

```
if(data) {
    ....
}
```

This will check for empty strings (`""`), `null`, `undefined`, `false` and the numbers `0` and `NaN`.

Comment: Though this wasn't the issue, it's really helpful to know. Thanks!

Comment: What about `0` or empty string `''`

Answer (score 2):

there is  difference between == and ===.
JavaScript has both strict(===) and type-converting(==) equality comparison.

Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding positions.
Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have the same number value). NaN is not equal to anything, including NaN. Positive and negative zeros are equal to one another.
Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or both are false.
Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object.
Null and Undefined types are == (but not ===). [I.e. Null==Undefined (but not Null===Undefined)]

```
if (data != null ) {
          console.log('Successful Login!');
          console.log('Returned data: ' + data);
        } else {
          console.log('Failed to Login...');
        }
```